# MapKit pan and request data to server

Tags: ios, annotations, mapkit, region

I have some questions about MapKit. 
I have to Implement an efficient way to visualize some mapAnnotations on my map.

To visualize this annotation I need to call to my API server where I specific lat, long and distance.

I understood that I need to call my server When the user make a pan on the map: I need to implement this code into this MapKit delegate method.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

I need to Implement this as efficiently as possible .. I thought, for example, of this solution but I do not know if this is the better way or there is some standard methods ..

I can calculate the area that I covered with my last request. When the user performs a pan I'll verify if the new area is still covered by the last request.

Could be ok? Do you know something that implements this?

Answer (score 0):

Once i had to deal with it in my project.

So, what i did is, i made a server `request with larger map Area` (say 10 times more than what is `currently visible on map`).So this way i don't need to make too many request to server for each pan and new region.

And i had to create a `MKMapRect array` to store each region i made the request. And before making a server call i had to check whether the current `visible mapRect` contains inside any of those rects.(*actually above array behaves like a queue*)

And i suggest you to use below method.

```
- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView
```

because there is no meaning to show annotations unless the map has downloaded.